# How to Remove spaces between sections of UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am creating a UICollectionView sections but I am getting spaces between them. I want my sections to immediately start one after other with no space in between

How to do this?

**I Want something like this-**

[image]

**I am getting this-**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to google it before?

Comment: Yes and I had tried solutions but its not working. @Praveen

Comment: What's your actual requirement? You don't want empty space between sections. Right?

Answer (score 0):

In `Interface Builder`, select your `UICollectionView`, go to `Size Inspector`. Here you can set `Section Insets` to reduce space between sections.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to reduce the space between sections,

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return CGSizeZero;
}
```